# Which preposition to use with Ebbe?

Tags: preposition

While investigating this sentence from Alles Licht, das wir nicht sehen, by Anthony Doerr, aus dem Englischen von Werner Löcher-Lawrence,

> Ihre größte Freude ist es, **bei Ebbe** ans nördliche Ende des Strandes zu gehen, sich hinter einer Insel, die Madame Manec Le Grand Bé nennt, hinzuhocken und mit den Händen durch die zurückgebliebenen Wasserlachen zu streichen.

I wondered about the use of bei in "bei Ebbe". I now believe this to be a fixed phrase meaning, "at low tide." But several [other prepositions are used with Ebbe](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=mit%20Ebbe%20%7C%7C%20von%20Ebbe&corpus=zeit&date-start=1946&date-end=2018&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50):

> Es hat sie immer gegeben, mal stärker, mal schwächer, sie gehorchen den Gesetzen **von Ebbe** und Flut, und derzeit herrscht Flut.

> Einfach nur die Schale aufklappen, und **mit Ebbe** und Flut kommt das Mahl automatisch des Weges geflossen.

Is there a logic to applying these prepositions, or are these also fixed phrases, with the option of either von or mit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not really different from any other languages. It depends on what you want to express. Mind also that "Ebbe und Flut" is a kind of fixed and commonly used expression synonymous to "Gezeiten" where English speakers might usually use "tides".

bei Ebbe --> at low tide

durch Ebbe und Flut --> (caused) by the tides. You can also use the higher register and say in German "durch die Gezeiten".

mit Ebbe und Flut --> (along with / by means of) the tides. Again, you can replace the fixed expression "Ebbe und Flut" by the higher-register "Gezeiten": "mit den Gezeiten..."

There simply is not one preposition going with a single noun - but the preposition determines the function of the noun in what you try to articulate. A noun by itself is not much - putting it into context creates a relation to other things and subjects.

Hausbau:
Der Hausbau ist anstrengend (building a house is exhausing)
Durch den Hausbau wurde die Aussicht verändert (building the house caused the view to change)
Mit dem Hausbau fing ein neuer Abschnitt an (the house building started a new phase
Während des Hausbaus war ich immer gestresst (While building the house I was always stressed)
Über den Hausbau haben wir vorher ausführlich darüber geredet (Before building the house we talked about it extensively)
Am Hausbau ansich ist nichts auszusetzen (Nothing wrong with building a house)
Vor dem Hausbau wohnte ich zur Miete (Before building a house I was renting)
Beim Hausbau muss man auf rechtzeitige Planung achten. (When building a house many things have to be taken into consideration)
...

Answer (score 1):

I can hardly imagine any noun that only occurs with one preposition - the preposition to use depends on what you're saying about the noun in your sentence.

> Auf dem Auto klebt ein Aufkleber. Mit dem Auto fahre ich nach Köln. Über das Auto kann ich nur Gutes sagen. Unter dem Auto liegt ein Mechaniker. Beim Auto steht mein Werkzeugkasten. Wegen des Autos muss ich nochmal zum Amt.

I think this becomes clear when you translate your example sentences (thanks DeepL):

> Her greatest joy is to go to the northern end of the beach **at low tide.**
> They obey the laws **of ebb and flow**.
> **With the ebb and flow of the tide**, the meal automatically flows along the way.

What you can say is that **bei** is the *temporal preposition of concurrency* for **Ebbe** and **Flut**.

> Am Samstag spielen wir Fußball am Strand.
> Im Sommer spielen wir Fußball am Strand.
> Bei Sonne spielen wir Fußball am Strand.
> Bei Ebbe spielen wir Fußball am Strand.